# Azure Bot Framework: Handle user sending multiple consecutive messages

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there any way for my bot to handle receiving multiple messages from users? For example, I (the bot) ask the user for some input, and that user instead of sending just one message with the info I need, sends it in 3 multiple messages.

The way my bot is developed now, it will handle the first message as the answer, and will handle the next message as the answer to the following question that would be made.

The way I would like it to work would be to make the bot "wait" for the user to send every message, maybe wait some seconds after every message to check no new one has been received, and then join them as one message and handle that.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but I don't think it is a recommended practice when developing bot.

The reason being it is hard to track which message are you receiving right now, 
except you record it using `PrivateConversationData`

some psuedo code:

```
await context.PostAsync("please reply 3 message");
context.Wait(ThreeMessageReceivedAsync);


private async Task ThreeMessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context,
    IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<string>("FirstMessage", out string firstMessage);
    context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<string>("SecondMessage", out string secondMessage);
    context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<string>("ThirdMessage", out string thirdMessage);

    var message = await result;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstMessage))
    {
        context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("FirstMessage", message.Text);
        context.Wait(ThreeMessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondMessage))
    {
        context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("SecondMessage", message.Text);
        context.Wait(ThreeMessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdMessage))
    {
        context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("ThirdMessage", message.Text);

        // you have got all three message, do your logic to it
        // if you want to join all three message, use variable firstMessage, secondMessage and message.Text for third
    }
}

hope above helps.
```